# Applying CSS rules based on input checkbox status

Tags: css, checkbox, transform, checked, rotatetransform

I'm currently developing a site that uses the :checked variable to apply rules to the CSS. I've got a checkbox input that when triggered, should accomplish two things. The first thing it should do is expand a div from a height of 0 to 200 when checked, and back to 0 when unchecked. I had no problems with triggering that first task. The second thing that *should* be accomplished upon checking the box, is a transform: rotate(45deg) of a div with a "**+"** in it that should rotate 45 degrees into an "**x**" (not an actual x, but a rotated +).

I've currently got my code setup to display the animation on :hover, but that's just for illustrative purposes, that wouldn't be in my final code. So hover over the "**+** to see what I'm trying to accomplish with the :checked input.

If you're willing to take a look at my [code](http://codepen.io/mtthwbckmn/pen/Actwn), and tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'd be greatly appreciative! Let me know if you have any questions.

**Note: Ideally I'm looking for a pure CSS solution without the need for JS. Let me know if this isn't possible.**

[Here's my code pen.](http://codepen.io/mtthwbckmn/pen/Actwn)

Comment: I have a solution; however it would require a change in the HTML - that's fine, right?

Comment: Now that I think about it... I can't think of a way to attach a `click handler` without JS :-(

Comment: @NicholasHazel Could you show me how you'd accomplish it with JS? The problem I've had with JS is getting it to toggleClass instead of addClass.

Comment: Added answer for jQuery solution. Add a few IDs and alter the class a lil. Done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a similar solution the other day, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272354/css-selector-doing-something-wrong/21272419#21272419).

Basically, you are limited when using the `:checked` method. You are relying on the [adjacent](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) and [general sibling combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators), [`+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators), [`~`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators). If the element isn't a general preceding sibling, it isn't going to work.

In this example, `.expand` was not a preceding sibling. Therefore the solution is to place the `input` element at the root of the document, and then use the selector `input[name='panel']:checked ~ label .rotate` to change the `.rotate` element. Note, that the general sibling combinator, `~` is now also being used as opposed to the adjacent sibling combinator, `+`.

No need for JS - [**UPDATED EXAMPLE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lFmzj)

**Modified HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="panel" class="hidden" id="panel"/>
<label for="panel">
  Click Me
  <div class="rotate">+</div>
</label>
<div class="expand">
  Content goes here.
</div>
```

**Updated CSS:**

```
input[name='panel']:checked ~ label .rotate {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

It's worth noting that I moved the transition properties to the `.rotate` element too.

Comment: This truly is beautiful! This is exactly what I was looking for, and I appreciate the explanation of why you changed the code. This was immensely helpful.

Comment: #panel:checked ~ label .rotate will be faster than input[name='panel'], especially on a page with a lot of input fields.

Answer (score 1):

## jQuery Solution:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/PUwh6/2/

**Use an `ID` so `jQuery` can map out what you're doing easily without searching for classes all over the place.**

**HTML:**

```
<label for="panel">
  Click Me
  <div id="rotate">+</div>
</label>
```

**CSS:**

```
#rotate {
 width: 12px;
 float: right;
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-top: -6px;
 text-align: center;
 transition: all 1s ease;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
 }
#rotate.spin {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#panel').on('click',function() {
  $('#rotate').toggleClass('spin');
});
```

Comment: Awesome. If I didn't already have the perfect CSS solution, this would have worked perfectly. Glad to know there's a simple second method. Thanks!

Comment: w00t @ 25pts :-) Thanks!